# IOError : [Error no: 21] is a directory : './w2v-model/wordmodel3'

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

```
def generate_w2vModel(decTokenFlawPath, w2vModelPath):
    print("training...")
    model = Word2Vec(sentences= DirofCorpus(decTokenFlawPath), size=30, alpha=0.01, window=5, min_count=0, max_vocab_size=None, sample=0.001, seed=1, workers=1, min_alpha=0.0001, sg=1, hs=0, negative=10, iter=5)
    model.save(w2vModelPath)

def evaluate_w2vModel(w2vModelPath):
    print("\nevaluating...")
    model = Word2Vec.load(w2vModelPath)
    for sign in ['(', '+', '-', '*', 'main']:
        print(sign, ":")
        print(model.most_similar_cosmul(positive=[sign], topn=10))

def main():
    dec_tokenFlaw_path = ['./data/cdg_ddg/corpus/']
    w2v_model_path = "./w2v_model/wordmodel3" 
    generate_w2vModel(dec_tokenFlaw_path, w2v_model_path)
    evaluate_w2vModel(w2v_model_path)
    print("success!")
```

this the python that i was running. This file is used to train word2vec model. The inputs are corpus files, and the output is the word2vec model. i got the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "create_w2vmodel.py", line 67, in <module>
    main()
  File "create_w2vmodel.py", line 62, in main
    generate_w2vModel(dec_tokenFlaw_path, w2v_model_path)
  File "create_w2vmodel.py", line 50, in generate_w2vModel
    model.save(w2vModelPath)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gensim-3.4.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/gensim/models/word2vec.py", line 930, in save
    super(Word2Vec, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gensim-3.4.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/gensim/models/base_any2vec.py", line 281, in save
    super(BaseAny2VecModel, self).save(fname_or_handle, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gensim-3.4.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/gensim/utils.py", line 691, in save
    self._smart_save(fname_or_handle, separately, sep_limit, ignore, pickle_protocol=pickle_protocol)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gensim-3.4.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/gensim/utils.py", line 550, in _smart_save
    pickle(self, fname, protocol=pickle_protocol)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gensim-3.4.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/gensim/utils.py", line 1311, in pickle
    with smart_open(fname, 'wb') as fout:  # 'b' for binary, needed on Windows
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/smart_open/smart_open_lib.py", line 89, in smart_open
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/smart_open/smart_open_lib.py", line 301, in file_smart_open
IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: './w2v_model/wordmodel3'
```

please help me to change this particular error. i think there is no folder like this, but i had already created the w2v_model/wordmodel3 in my folder. I had tried it in many ways. I will provide smart_open_lib.py program file below :

```
def file_smart_open(fname, mode='rb'):
    """
    Stream from/to local filesystem, transparently (de)compressing gzip and bz2
    files if necessary.

    """
    _, ext = os.path.splitext(fname)

    if ext == '.bz2':
        PY2 = sys.version_info[0] == 2
        if PY2:
            from bz2file import BZ2File
        else:
            from bz2 import BZ2File
        return make_closing(BZ2File)(fname, mode)

    if ext == '.gz':
        from gzip import GzipFile
        return make_closing(GzipFile)(fname, mode)

    return open(fname, mode)
```

this is the trace back code which they tell. kindly request to help me fr change this error!!!

Answer (score 0):

The `Word2Vec` `.save()` method needs a new path, to the filename (not directory!) to which you want to save the model's main file. (For most models of significant size, there will be extra files alongside that main file, with other extensions, that are also part of the model-save.)

If you're providing a path to an existing directory, you'll get an error like this.

Change your `w2v_model_path` to be a path to a desired file name, not an already-existing directory. (Perhaps that path will be *inside* that directory. But it shouldn't be the directory itself!)

Comment: i didn't understand what you says.. can you show an example???

Comment: `w2v_model_path = "./w2v_model/wordmodel3/SOME_FILENAME"` -not the directory, but a path to a filename you want it to use.

Comment: sir actually i am having 4 text files as my inputs, so how could i give this in the above path!!

Comment: None of your code shows any other use of the `w2v_model_path` variable, so changing `w2v_model_path` from its erroneous directory to an available file path should only affect the saving/loading of the module. The suggestion I've made should fix the exact error you've reported. (I can't guess at other code, or other errors, not shown in your question!)